# C# Can´t find the right objective in Collection

Tags: c#, collections

I made this method to make sure that the user can't use the same object of a datagrid. The datagrid contains custom objects. The first column is the name of a document, the 2nd a drawing number which I get with a method from the document name and the 3rd contains an index which I get with the same procedure. In the last columns there is the Extension of the Documents. Users aren't allowed to use multiple documents with same drawing number and extension for the next step in my program. But sometimes for reason it seems that my method don't work because you can go on with files you should not. I have absolutely no idea why this happen. Sometimes it doesn't even work when you select two documents. Sometimes it works when you select all documents in the datagrid.

**EDIT:**

So I think the problem here is exactly at the finding of the right index.
Because I can have multiple documents in the DataGrid with the same drawing number but with different extensions. And there I have the problem. So when I get the Index of the drawing number I look the Extension up, but the Extension I'm looking for can be at position one and the document object maybe at six and so the object will be added. And this is exactly what I don't want to allow. Has anyone an idea how can I solve this quickly?

```
int i_zeichnung = my_list.FindIndex(x => x.Zeichnungsnummer.Equals(file.AdditionalColumn));
int i_extension = my_list.FindIndex(y => y.Extension.Equals(file.AdditionalColumn4));

if (i_zeichnung == i_extension && i_zeichnung > -1 && i_extension > -1)
    MessageBox.Show("Error");
else
    my_list.Add(inDB);
```

Comment: Please don't post your entire long method worth of code and ask us to debug it all. If you provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your problem, we will be able to help much more effectively. (And chances are that in doing so, you may discover the problem yourself.)

Comment: What do you mean with Random bug? Every time a different unrelated error, or the same error that you cannot pin point?

Comment: May else/if nested this way may cause **racing conditions**, or unexpected results. That is, not al if/else result will not always execute the correct business rules. So the problem is in the design of your code. I strongly advise to go back to the drawing board, create a diagram that clarifies what you need to implement and walk trough all relevant scenarios. You will see that you can optimize your code drastically! (and it will work)

Comment: Do yourself (and us) a favor and split up this too deeply nested method into several methods with a clear, single purpose.

Comment: I edited my problem above.